# Problem in using FindFit

Tags: fitting

I have the following set of data

```
data={{0,0,0},{0,2,1},{0,4,2.247},{0,6,3.627},{0,8,5.031},{1,0,3.346}};
```

where the values are {n, L,$\varepsilon$} and satisfy the following equations

$E(n,L) = 2n+1 + \sqrt{L(L+1)-\frac{3}{4}(L)^2 + 1 + \beta_0^4}$

```
e[n_, L_] = 2n + 1 + Sqrt[L(L + 1) - 3/4 L^2 + 1 + b0^4]
```

$\varepsilon = \frac{E(n,L)-E(0,0)}{E(0,2)-E(0,0)}$,

where $\beta_0$ should be determined. I don't know how I can use FindFit command of Mathematica to find the best value of $\beta_0$ to have the best fit for $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
e[n_, L_] = 2n + 1 + Sqrt[L(L + 1) - 3/4 L^2 + 1 + b0^4]

FindFit[data, (e[n, L] - e[0, 0])/(e[0, 2] - e[0, 0]), b0, {n, L}]
```

> {b0 -> 1.3514967}

Which seems reasonable in view of the residuals:

```
Plot[Evaluate[(e[#, #2] - e[0, 0])/(e[0, 2] - e[0, 0]) - #3 & @@@ data], {b0, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

The brown and purple residual has bigger slope around the roots in the plots. Hence for Mathematica to minimize the sum of squares in the y-dimension, the mean of the 2 data points that correspond to the big slopes are cared more about than the others. It is purpose specific whether this is appropriate. If it isn't you can add the `NormFunction`-option to `FindFit`.

Comment: Thank you dear @Coolwater. How does Mathematica recognize {n,L} for each data?

Comment: Also, how does it recognize that the expr is the 3rd value of every data element?

Comment: `FindFit` assumes its first argument has the form `{{var1, var2, ..., varN, expr}, ... , {var1, var2, ..., varN, expr}}` where `{var1, var2, ..., varN}` is the 4th argument of `FindFit`

Comment: Ok!  Given b -> {1.27225, 1.29505, 1.28573, 1.40411}  having Mean=1.31428  and Medean=1.29039  do you think Mathematica did a good job? Anyway +1 from me

Comment: @J42161217 It uses least squares, see edit

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `NMinimize`. First we need to write cost function, i.e. residual.

```
data = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 1}, {0, 4, 2.247}, {0, 6, 3.627}, {0, 8, 
    5.031}, {1, 0, 3.346}};
e[n_, L_] := 2 n + 1 + Sqrt[L (L + 1) - 3/4 L^2 + 1 + b0^4]
cost[b0_] =Sum[(e @@data[[i, 1 ;; 2]] - (data[[i, 3]] (e[0, 2] - e[0, 0]) + 
      e[0, 0]))^2, {i, 6}];
(*or Total[(e[#1, #2] - (#3 (e[0, 2] - e[0, 0]) + e[0, 0]))^2 & @@@ data]*)

fit = NMinimize[cost[b0] , b0]
```

> {0.0196376, {b0 -> 1.35462}}

Since your cost function has only one variable you can also use grid search.

`Ordering[val,1]` gives position of min value.

```
b0Val = Range[0, 10, 0.0001];
val = cost[b0Val];
b0Val[[Ordering[val, 1]]]
```

> {1.3546}

Note that there is another min at `b0=-1.3546`

```
b0Val = Range[-1000, 1000, 0.001];    
val = cost[b0Val];    
b0Val[[Ordering[val, 2]]]
```

> {-1.3546, 1.3546}

We can plot cost function

$\text{cost}(b0)=\left(-5.031 \left(\sqrt{\text{b0}^4+4}-\sqrt{\text{b0}^4+1}\right)-\sqrt{\text{b0}^4+1}+\sqrt{\text{b0}^4+25}\right)^2\\+\left(-3.627
   \left(\sqrt{\text{b0}^4+4}-\sqrt{\text{b0}^4+1}\right)-\sqrt{\text{b0}^4+1}+
\sqrt{\text{b0}^4+16}\right)^2\\+\left(2-3.346
   \left(\sqrt{\text{b0}^4+4}-\sqrt{\text{b0}^4+1}\right)\right)^2+\left(-2.247
   \left(\sqrt{\text{b0}^4+4}-\sqrt{\text{b0}^4+1}\right)-\sqrt{\text{b0}^4+1}+\sqrt{\text{b0}^4+9}\right)^2$

```
Plot[cost[b0], {b0, -10, 10}]
```

[image]